# How to resolve Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I used following code to replace a html element, I am using ngbTypeahead from ng bootstrap.

`HTML`

```
    <input [resultTemplate]="rt" [ngbTypeahead]="search">
    <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
     <span class="dropdown-heading" [ngClass]="onType()">
     </span>
    </ng-template>
```

`component`

```
  import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

  class TestComponent {
    element;

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    onType(): void {
     this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-heading');
     const element = document.createElement('b');
     const textnode = document.createTextNode("stack");
     element.appendChild(textnode);
     for (let i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++) {
       this.element[i].parentNode.replaceWith(element);
     }
    }
  }
```

Getting following error. How can I resolve this?

`ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Comment: What's `this.elementRef` and `this.element[i]`? You need to provide a little more code to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Updated code, I am using angular

Comment: Nope, keep going. We need more code and why is the code you posted sitting outside of the constructor?

Comment: replaceWith() returns the set of elements that was removed, so here unable to remove as that element is not the child of the node referred

Comment: If you are not inside a loop, then how your index i in this.element[i] is working?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I updated code @Fuzz

Comment: This error usually occurs when you try to access a `DOM` node which is not present in the `DOM` tree. Can you try verifying that is your `DOM` node actually getting inserted before you access it?

Comment: Okay, what's `i`? You're almost there :)

Comment: Please ignore that, updated code.

Comment: You named two different var 'element'. It's confusing. this.element is an HTML Collection and const element is a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you got yourself a logic error.

You're replacing the parent **and all of its contents** of the first element. Therefore removing all other elements in the collection.

The second time your loop comes around it tries to replace in an element which is no longer in the DOM.

Concider the following example

```js
const element = document.createElement('p');
const textnode = document.createTextNode("just goodbye");
element.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById('bye').parentNode.replaceWith(element);
```

```html
<p>
  Hello World
  <span id="bye">And Goodbye</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. On typing new letter, typeahead values will differ. Please suggest solution in my scenario.

Comment: I'd leave DOM manipulation to Angular and feed the typeahead with a list. Render the list with a for loop as described here: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: If you think my answer answered your original question, consider marking is as 'accepted'. You can always file a new question to describe the problems you experience with getting typeahead suggestions working. And may I suggest looking into the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

this.element is a HTML collection. When you do

```
document.getElementsClassName('hello');
```

It return a collection of element which matches this class (it could contain only one element)
So when you are trying to do `this.element.parentNode` you are trying to find the parentNode of an array.

Try `this.element[0].parentNode.replaceWith(element);`

Comment: Updated code. Yes I used for loop. Same issue facing.